# Make mysqlpp::Connection object private member of wxFrame class object

Tags: c++, g++, mysql++

I'm getting errors trying to build code that has a mysqlpp::Connection object as a private member of my wxFrame object.

```
class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
    public:
        MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
    private:
        mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);


        wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();        
};
```

G++ gives the following errors.

```
C:\TestApp\testapp.cpp:31:28: error: expected identifier before 'false'
   mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);
                        ^
C:\TestApp\testapp.cpp:31:28: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'false'
C:\TestApp\testapp.cpp: In member function 'int MyFrame::Initialization()':
C:\TestApp\testapp.cpp:102:6: error: '((MyFrame*)this)->MyFrame::conn' does not have class type
  if (conn.connect("xxxxxxxxxxx", "localhost", "xxxx", "xxxxxxxx", xxxx))
      ^
C:\TestApp\testapp.cpp:104:26: error: '((MyFrame*)this)->MyFrame::conn' does not have class type
   mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query("SELECT xxxxxxxxxxxxxx FROM xxxxxxxxxxx");
                          ^
C:\TestApp\testapp.cpp: In member function 'void MyFrame::OnClose(wxCloseEvent&)':
C:\TestApp\testapp.cpp:136:2: error: '((MyFrame*)this)->MyFrame::conn' does not have class type
  conn.disconnect();
  ^
C:\TestApp\testapp.cpp: In member function 'void MyFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent&)':
C:\TestApp\testapp.cpp:143:2: error: '((MyFrame*)this)->MyFrame::conn' does not have class type
  conn.disconnect();
  ^
```

There is other code below this that attempts to call the `connect()` and `disconnect()` methods for the object, but as the errors indicate, this is not recognized.

Even when I use the following...

```
mysqlpp::Connection conn();
```

... allowing the constructor to use the default initialization, the compiler still throws all of the errors except those for line 31.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This field declaration seems weird.

```
mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);
```

Try `mysqlpp::Connection conn;` and initialize it within initializer list in constructor.

Comment: That was the problem.  I pulled that form from the examples in the MySQL++ documentation, but the only examples I saw were for console apps.  I didn't make the conversion to the wxWidgets (on win32) app correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: It's nothing to do with console vs wxWidgets, you copied the declaration of a local variable and tried to use it as a class member. C++ doesn't work like that.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading that when an object is declared in a class, the constructor is not called?  Is this the case?  I couldn't get unhooked from needing to send it an initializer.  Or maybe it is just using the defaults.

Comment: You don't *construct* variables in the class definition, you only *declare* them. The construction happens in the *constructor*. In this case, use C++'s initializer list syntax: `MyFrame::MyFrame() : conn(false) { }` Oh, and by the way, are you sure you want to suppress exceptions like this?

Comment: Understood on the difference between construction and declaration.  From what I've seen, it seems that in many classes, the constructor (proper) is called automatically and not by the user.  In reference to suppressing exceptions, at the point that I was using that, I was just working on a proof of concept to myself by cutting and pasting things from your examples in the MySQL++ documentation.  I've actually taken that out in my working code.

Comment: . . .  I've been looking around for a straight forward C++ wrapper to access my MariaDB database.  Yours is the one that I finally broke through on after having tried some others and even developing on Postgresql for a little while since the C connector was pretty straight forward.  I've been trying to migrate back MySQL (actually MariaDB).  It was super easy to build MySQL++ against the libmysql.dll included with MariaDB 10.0.16.  That's why I went with it.  I'm just trying to get up to speed now.  Kudos on the excellent wrapper (in my inexperienced opinion).